# Django request.method == 'POST' returning false

Tags: javascript, django, web-applications, django-forms, django-views

Currently working on my first django web application so still quite rusty. 
Trying to create a page that allows a lecturer to create a new class, the class is then added to the lecturers list of classes.

As far as I can tell, from following a tutorial, the request.method in my views.py should return a POST, but is currently returning GET.

Because of this, the new class created is never saved to the database.

here is my views.py

```
def create_class(request):
if request.user.is_lecturer:

    print(" ")
    print("user is lecturer")
    form = classForm()
    print(request.method)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print("")
        print("request method equals post")
        form = classForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():

            lecturer = LecturerProfile.objects.get(lecturer=request.user)
            subject = Class.objects.get_or_create(class_name=form.cleaned_data["class_name"],
                                                      class_description=form.cleaned_data["class_description"],
                                                      lecturer=lecturer)
            LecturerProfile.Classes.add(subject)
            form.save(commit=True)
            return index(request)
        else:
            print("")
            print(form.errors)

    else:
        print("")
        print("request method fail")
else:
    return HttpResponse("You are not allowed here")

return render(request, 'student_feedback_app/create_class.html', {'form':form})
```

forms.py

```
class classForm(forms.ModelForm):
subject = forms.CharField(max_length=40, help_text="Class Name", required=False)
class_description = forms.CharField(max_length=200, required=False, help_text="Class Description")
slug = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), required=False)

class Meta:
    model = Class
    fields = ('subject', 'class_description',)
```

my create_class.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
Create a new class

<h1> Create a new class</h1>
</head>

<body>
<div>
    <form id="" method="post" action="/lecturer/classes/">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
            {{ hidden }}
        {% endfor %}
        {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
                    <br>
                    {{ field.errors }}
                    {{ field.help_text }}
                    {{ field }}
        {% endfor %}
        <br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create Class" /> </form>

</div>
</body>

</html>
```

The errors that I get out at the terminal are

> user is lecturer GET
>
> request method fail
>
> [11/Nov/2018 16:27:24] "GET /lecturer/create-class/ HTTP/1.1" 200 923
>
> Not Found: /lecturer/create-class/js/plugins/jqBootstrapValidation.js
>
> [11/Nov/2018 16:27:24] "GET /lecturer/create-class/js/plugins/jqBootstrapValidation.js HTTP/1.1" 404 4369

From the errors it would seem like it must be something to do with Bootstrap that the error is coming from, although i haven't used this for anything. 
I even took out the base_template.html and wrote the create_class.html normally incase something from it was using javascript and bootstrap, but got the same output. 
Any help is very appreciated

Comment: Are you sure with your form? client side? check with the network debugger if you really post the data.

Comment: I'm sorry but im afraid I'll need a little bit more instructions on how to check that. Do you mean by using the admin interface? or using an actual debugging tool like Pdb

Comment: No, it won't be POST until you submit the form. The first request, to display the form, will be GET.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Ah yeah i've realised that now, this however still doesnt help, as once the form is submitted im stuck in the same position where the data isnt being saved. Also once I hit submit, surely nothing will happen as I've already dropped out of the if, does it not have to equal POST to begin with?

Comment: Well, there are several errors here, but the most obvious is that `if request.POST.get("create_class")` will never be true because you don't have anything in your form called "create_class". What's the point of that condition? And I don't understand what you mean by "I've already dropped out of the if".

Comment: @DanielRoseman I was unsure what that line did, as it was just in the tutorial i was reading through, so have taken it out and will update the question. However the error still persists sadly.